# how can I add titles from a custom config array in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, config

I'm trying to display the title of my pages with config. I haven't done anything in .env files and not even given the namespaces for the config to use. Config can be used globally right?

here is my config:

```
return [

        'page' => [

            'home'          => 'Home',
            'overview'      => 'Overview',
            'A-type-room'   => 'A-type-Room',
            'B-type-room'   => 'B-type-Room',
            'booking'       => 'Booking',
            'meeting'       => 'Meeting',
            'gallery'       => 'Gallery',
            'review'        => 'Review',
            'activity'      => 'Activities',
            'contact'       => 'Contact'

];
```

Here is my header.blade.php

```
<title>

    {{Config::get('customConfig.page.home')}}


</title>
```

Comment: You can use config() helper function to get the value of the config option. I assume you have a file named `customConfig.php` in your config directory.

IMP - Yes, config options can be accessed from anywhere but using then for page titles is not a good use case. I would suggest you to put title directly in your blade files.

Comment: I assume this isn't actually working? You may need to clear the config cache if you've added a new config file. Try running `php artisan config:cache` followed by `php artisan config:clear` followed by `php artisan cache:clear` (I know, it seems weird you have to do all of those, but it's the most reliable method.

Comment: That said, as you're adding titles, why not do it in a localisation file? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: If you have a new question, then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). **Do not** replace an existing question with a new one, thus invalidating the answers you already have by making them nonsensical in context.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to pass page titles dynamically..

In your every controller use a common variable as $title.
Echo the $title in the header.

```
{{ $title }}
```

Then load title with view.

```
public function index(){
   $title = "Home";
   return view('index)->withTitle("Home");}
```